# Unexpected list of items on #index

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table

On my index page, I succeeded in listing all of my 'games' in a table, unfortunately, another list, that isn't part of my index.html.erb file code also appears, above my table.
I don't understand how this is possible as my html file doesn't contain any element at the place the list appears on the browser... If someone has an idea that would be very nice !

Here's a photo of what appears on the browser :
[browser problem snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFMBb.png)

Here's my index.html.erb code :

```
<div class="container full-height">
  <div class="abs-center">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">GAMES</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%= @games.reverse.each do |g| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= g.id %></td>
            <td><%= g.score_1 %></td>
            <td><%= g.score_2 %></td>
            <td><%= g.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'see game', game_path(g) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'modify', edit_game_path(g) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

My game controller index method :

```
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `=` before `<%= @games.reverse.each do |g| %>`. `=` renders a result of an expression, in your case, it is `each` method, that returns the collection.

Must look as this `<% @games.reverse.each do |g| %>`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much ! I fell a little dumb but thanks !