# rails html file printing unwanted data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

i'm very new to rails and html and i'm not sure why this piece of code is printing an array of data that i didn't ask for at the bottom of my web page. I need help with getting rid of them from my web page.

show.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <%= @category.products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.id %></td>
      <td><%= product.size %></td>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= @category.products.each do |product| %>
  <h3><%= product.id %></h3>
  <h3><%= product.size %></h3>
  <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
<% end %>
```

screenshot of the website [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qb1m.jpg), red arrows are pointing to the unwanted data

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836593/unexpected-list-of-items-on-index/62836877#62836877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<%= @category...` to `<% @category.` on both of your loops.
By including the `=` `erb` is printing out the whole object on each loop (but you just want to read from the object)

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've written any ERB code, but from what I remember the `<%=` operator prints the result to the output. So you should be able to convert those `<%=` to `<%` so that ERB knows to execute the ruby code, but not include the result in the output.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% @category.products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.id %></td>
      <td><%= product.size %></td>
      <td><%= product.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<% @category.products.each do |product| %>
  <h3><%= product.id %></h3>
  <h3><%= product.size %></h3>
  <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
<% end %>
```